# How to crop text inside a grid block that does not fit

Tags: css, text, css-grid

I have an simple example code.
Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/Tux_Enhanced.svg/154px-Tux_Enhanced.svg.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  outline: 1px solid;
  grid-template-columns: 80px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 80px;
}

img {
  height: 80px;
}

.text {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

THis: https://jsfiddle.net/6f7yukho/
When I reduce the size of the browser, I see that the container block is growing and the text is not cropped.
The text should not be moved to another line but should be cut off, how can this be done?

Comment: Paulie_D, not working https://jsfiddle.net/x2ye935b/

Comment: The line wraps to the next line, I need to always have one line

Comment: ahhh, then https://jsfiddle.net/gjn41dcp/

Comment: there is also line-clamp and text-overflow to look at :  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need:

use `white-space: nowrap;` in your content and the code which you have used `overflow:hidden;` will take care of the rest.

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/8vLodh19/6/)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  outline: 1px solid;
  grid-template-columns: 80px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 80px;
 
}

img {
  height: 80px;
}
#hideText{
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/Tux_Enhanced.svg/154px-Tux_Enhanced.svg.png">
  </div>
  <div id="hideText">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works. But why does text-overflow: ellipsis not work? https://jsfiddle.net/x2ye935b/2/

Comment: The fiddle you gave is working as per your requirement!

Comment: `text-overflow:ellpsis;` only works when containers property should be `override:hidden/scroll/auto and white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: The problem was in the p tag. I just removed it and it worked

Answer (score -1):

Move the text class up to the block that contains both p tags:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  outline: 1px solid;
  grid-template-columns: 80px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 80px;
}

img {
  height: 80px;
}

.text {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/Tux_Enhanced.svg/154px-Tux_Enhanced.svg.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```